# linker can't find lua library

Tags: lua, linker, g++

I ran `g++ -g ./src/*.cpp -L/usr/lib/ -llua5.3`

and got an error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llua5.3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I make linker find lua library?
I've installed lua with this commands

```
wget -R -O http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.3.0.tar.gz
tar zxf lua-5.3.0.tar.gz
cd lua-5.4.2
make linux 
make install
```

Comment: Are you sure the static library has been installed in `/usr/lib/` and not in `/usr/local/lib/`?

Comment: You're making lua-5.4.2, not lua-5.3.0. Also, the library will be named liblua.a and so use `-llua`.

Comment: I changed `-llua5.3` to `-llua` and got 
`/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/liblua.a(loadlib.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed `apt install liblua5.3-dev` instead of `wget -R -O http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.3.0.tar.gz` to make it work